# Function that gets n times zero value, is it derivative gets n-1 times 0 value?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I faced the following question while practising exams in calculus :

$f(x)$ is a function that is **continuous** in $[a,b]$ and **differentiate** in $(a,b)$.
If $f(x)$ gets exactly $n$ times zero value (means $f(x) = 0$ occur $n$ times), then it's derivative $f'(x)$ gets $n-1$ times zero value.

On one hand, I couldn't find any function that it's derivative gets $n-2$ times zero value. But on the other hand, I don't know how to prove that.

Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean "occurs $n$ times"?  Do you mean that $f$ has exactly $n$ distinct roots?

Comment: do you know the Rolle's Theorem?

Comment: I was afraid this question was going to be about [this mathematical joke](https://mathoverflow.net/a/4420)...

Answer (score 1):

Its derivative $f'$ has *at least* $n-1$ zeroes. Because between any two zeroes of $f$, there is *at least* one zero of $f'$, by [Rolle's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem).